# How to prevent cursor shift when using <C-O>{delete cmd} at the end of a line?

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, insert-mode, cursor-motions, map-operator

`<C-w>` deletes a (small-)word in insert mode, but I often want to delete the Word (to last whitespace) I've most recently typed. I tried

`inoremap <C-_> <C-o>dB`

which kind-of works -- except that at the end of the line, `<C-o>` moves the cursor left one character (and so the last character survives the deletion).

Other options? More generally, how do I use `<C-o>` in insert-mode mappings without the end-of-line off-by-one problem? Can the normal-mode cursor (which is what `<C-o>` summons) be placed "temporarily" beyond the line-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is insert `<C-\>` before the `<C-o>`.

```
inoremap <C-_> <C-\><C-o>dB
```

Help for `i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O` says:

> CTRL-\ CTRL-O : like CTRL-O but don't move the cursor

That's it. Well except for a caveat or two which I'll reproduce here for your convenience ;) ...

> The CTRL-O command sometimes has a side effect: If the cursor was
> beyond the end of the line, it will be put on the last character in
> the line.  In mappings [you can] use CTRL-\ CTRL-O, but then beware of
> the cursor possibly being beyond the end of the line.  Note that the
> command following CTRL-\ CTRL-O can still move the cursor, it is not
> restored to its original position.

While quickly testing your mapping with the fix against the scenario you describe I didn't see any issues so you can probably safely ignore all of that.